# using signalR .net core client

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, signalr.client, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

I have set up a signalR website .net core. My function in my hub is:

```
public async Task Notify(int id) {
    await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Notified", id);
}
```

I have also tested this with the following js:

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnection(myURL);

    connection.on('Notified', data => {
        console.log(4, data);
    });

    connection.start();
```

The js code seems to work fine and I see the log when I try `connection.Invoke('Notify')`.

Now I have a console app that can needs to make the invoke. I am trying this in two ways and don't mind either solution:
1. A mvc controller within the signalR website that can take the id and invoke 'Notified'.
2. Use the client library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` in the console app.

The way **1** I have only done in classic asp.net like this:

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(hubName)
```

But couldn't find a way to do this in .net core.

Way **2** I have used the library and tried this so far:

```
var con = new HubConnectionBuilder();
con.WithUrl(myURL);      
var connection = con.Build();
connection.InvokeAsync("Notify",args[0]).Wait();
```

This is the closest I have come to create a connection in the same way as the js code. However this code throws a null pointer when calling `connection.InvokeAsync`. The `connection` object is not null. It seems to be an internal object that is null. According to the stack trace the exception is thrown when a MoveNext() function is internally called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looks like both are not currently possible. As of now I just used a forced way which is hopefully temporary.

I have created and used the following base class for hubs:

```cs
public abstract class MyHub : Hub
{

    private static Dictionary<string, IHubClients> _clients = new Dictionary<string, IHubClients>();

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var c = base.OnConnectedAsync();
        _clients.Remove(Name);
        _clients.Add(Name, Clients);
        return c;
    }

    public static IHubClients GetClients(string Name) {
        return _clients.GetValueOrDefault(Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: As per my response you injecting IHubContext is a replacement for GlobalHost - here is some code: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/884

Comment: LOL! what's with the -1? does this NOT WORK for someone?

Comment: The response is not correct - it says both are not possible while the first is actually possible and the second is probably caused by trying to send without starting the connection. Still a bug in SignalR (note we are talking about an alpha version) but without starting a connection you can't  expected anything will be sent. (full stack trace for the NullReferenceException would be helpful in pin pointing where the issue is and would allow help fixing the code so that it works).

Comment: As you have clearly mentioned, this method is a REPLACEMENT for GlobalHost. It isn't a class replacement but a process replacing the class. When I said it is not possible, I was referring to there not being a direct class replacement. My code here too is a process replacement of GlobalHost. That doesn't make the answer wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. GlobalHost is gone. You need to inject `IHubContext<THub>` like in [this sample.](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/blob/1fa7d8a330e77dcd21ced9220670c8772c1610a7/StockTickR/StockTickRApp/StockTicker.cs#L29)
2. This can be a bug in SignalR alpha1. Can you file an issue on https://github.com/aspnet/signalr and include a simplified repro?